# Polymorphism in generic classes not working in C++0x

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, type-erasure

Basically from C++ FAQ I learned that:

> A virtual function allows derived classes to replace the
>   implementation provided by the base class. The compiler makes sure the
>   replacement is always called whenever the object in question is
>   actually of the derived class, even if the object is accessed by a
>   base pointer rather than a derived pointer. This allows algorithms in
>   the base class to be replaced in the derived class, even if users
>   don't know about the derived class.

Though, using templates this becomes no more correct.

I need to have a template class which is derived by another template class. After that I found it makes no sense to have a virtual function in a base template class, googling around I found that there is a technique to overcome limitations of polymorphism in generic programming called Type Erasure.

Examples and tutorials I've read, are almost irrelevant to my needs. Also I'm not sure if I understood concepts of Type Erasure correctly. Being a beginner, I need to simply do:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void doX(){cout<<"doX from Foo"<<endl;}
};

template <typename T>
class Bar : public Foo<T>
{
public:
    void doX(){cout<<"doX from Bar"<<endl;}
};
```

And,

```
Foo<int>* p;
Foo<int> i;
i.doX();           // "doX from Foo", it's ok
Bar<int> j;
j.doX();           // "doX from Bar", it's ok
p=&i;
p->doX();          // should be "doX from Foo", it's ok
p=&j;
p->doX();          // I expect "doX from Bar", but it's "doX from Foo"
```

**EDIT:**
My question is how to implement above behavior? Without templates, It works as expected. I need same for general classes.

Simply, I have a base class `B`. It's a template class. It has a virtual function. And also I have a subclass of `B` which is a template class too, and it should reimplement some behavior of  `B` (somehow implement virtual function of `B`).

**EDIT2 : Just edited the title.**
I was compiling my code with g++ 4.6.3 compiler using flag `-std=c++0x` because I need `std::thread` and `std::unique_ptr` in my code. Surprisingly, removing the `-std=c++0x` the above code works as expected. I also tried g++ 4.7 and there was no problem with both 2011 and 2003 standards.

Comment: @Desolator I just edited my question.

Comment: The last `p->doX()` prints "doX from Bar" when I run this code. Please make sure the code above really prints that unexpected message you report. If so, specify your compiler, it might be a bug.

Comment: Agree with @eran, I was quite puzzled when I saw the question and I tried it with Xcode, and the expected result above was printed out. What compiler + environment are you using that gave you the unexpected result?

Comment: @eran I'm pretty sure about output. I'm using g++ 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: Get the correct result with MSVC++ 10.0 (Visual Studio 2010). Since someone else tested with gcc and it worked as well, we're now pretty limited wrt available compilers.. clang, borland?

Comment: It's interesting. I have no access to any other compiler right now, so do some online tests with ideone.com and codepad.com. Both have expected output. see "http://ideone.com/rrQDN" and "http://codepad.org/F0nZZabM"

Comment: I do only have access to an old g++ (4.5.3) under cygwin at the moment, but that does print the correct value as well. Either you misremember, changed something when testing at home or g++ 4.6.3 has some *really* problematic bug.

Comment: Please somebody test the code with g++!

Comment: Okay... I'm a little frightened. I just tested again, it's wrong here... My friend says it's true for him. (We have same compilers). Am I in a parallel world?

Comment: @sorush-r, how you compile? Show compile string please.

Comment: @ForEveR `g++ -c -pipe -std=c++0x -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++0x -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -o robot.o robot.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o c++-mutal main.o robot.o     -pthread -lpthread `

Comment: @sorush-r Try to not use -std=c++0x... I don`t think that it`s problem, but i have no other ideas.

Comment: removing C++0x makes it work! Though I used a lot of `std::unique_ptr` in my code. Sometimes I want to kill C++ technical committee guys.

Comment: @ForEveR Please mention about C++0x in your answer. I'm gonna accept it. Thanks ;)

Comment: Well now the really interesting question is why the hell this shouldn't work with `std=c++0x` - seems like a bug to me, but maybe it's really undefined behavior? But no I think it's probably a bug in g++..

Comment: @Voo I tried g++ 4.7 on another computer. There was no problem. And also g++ 4.6.3 (same version) for my friend works fine with both 2011 and 2003 standards! So I think there is no such a huge bug in g++. It's probably a fault of configuring/compiling the compiler by the package maintainer team. I'm gonna change my OS...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because function doX is not virtual. In derived class you hide function doX, not overload, so dynamic polymorphysm not work.

**EDIT.**
GCC 4.6.3 have bug in such case, when you use -std=c++0x flag.
**EDIT2.**
Possibly GCC 4.6.3 have no such bug and problem is with TS compiler.

Comment: @sorush-r, in such case it works. [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/13ffaaf2c0618ec415c9d9ff317d7a67)

Comment: @sorush-r, click link please, and see the output.
doX from Foo
doX from Bar
doX from Foo
doX from Bar

Comment: @FoEveR You're probably using DevC++ compiler. For me, output is `doX from Foo` `doX from Bar` `doX from Foo` `doX from Foo`

Comment: @sorush-r No. I use gcc4.7.0 and MSVC 12 RC, output is equal. Which compiler you use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it won't work because the p is assigned to i pointer, and i is type of Foo. You are using the baseclass function. You should make the baseclass function pure virtual (by adding `= 0` at the end of the function). Then it should work.

Edit: I didn't notice it was checked as OK by you, thought that would be the error. Tried the code by myself with msvc compiler, and it did work as intended.

Comment: Wrong. Class not must be abstract for use dynamic polymorphysm.

Comment: What if I need a non-pure virtual function?

Comment: @sorush-r it's probably just a compiler bug because it worked for me when I tested your code.